# What is the method that called in uitableviewcell last?

Tags: uitableview, drawrect

I have table view and custom cells in it. My custom cells have a multiline label therefore I have to implement code to change the label's height. I put it to layoutSubviews.
But I have trouble. Cells are shown incorrectly. I started debagging with NSLog.
I found that layoutSubviews called not last (I checked init method, layoutSubview, willDisplayCell (table view delegate method), drawRect and prepareForSegue). Last one is drawRect method. My solution was to call layoutSubviews in drawRect and this helped for the first time table view appear. But if I switch between views drawRect methods not called any more and I have same bug. I can show screenshots if you want, but I really need your advice, guys.

PS: English is my main trouble, I know, sorry. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found awesome solution myself. The trick is to create in table view data source NSArray with images which will have rounded corners already. I did it such direction:

**1.1 Add QuartzCore framework to project.**

**1.2 Then add category for UIImage. UIImage+RoundedCorners.h:**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface UIImage (RoundedCorners)

    - (UIImage *)imageWithRoundedCorners:(CGFloat)radius;

    @end
```

**1.3 UIImage+RoundedCorners.m:**

```
    #import "UIImage+RoundedCorners.h"
    #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

    @implementation UIImage (RoundedCorners)

    - (UIImage *)imageWithRoundedCorners:(CGFloat)radius;
    {
        CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
        imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
        imageLayer.contents = (id)self.CGImage;

        imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
        imageLayer.cornerRadius = radius;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);
        [imageLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return roundedImage;
    }

    @end
```

**2.1 Create NSArray (NSMutableArray) with images you want to use:**

```
    _thumbnailImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[_dishes count]];
    for (int counter = 0; counter < [_dishes count]; counter++) 
    {
        EBEntityDish *dish = [_dishes objectAtIndex:counter];
        [_thumbnailImages addObject:[dish.image.thumbnailImage imageWithRoundedCorners:IMAGE_CORNER_RADIUS]];
    }
```

**2.2 Notes:**

```
    IMAGE_CORNER_RADIUS == your image corner radius.
    _dishes - My objects that contain images small size (144 x 144)
```

**2.3 Results:**

```
    My FPS increased on 10 - 20 FPS! Really awesome! Good luck!
```